# Reference request: learning Fontaine-Messing theory

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-hodge-theory

I am interested in learning about Fontaine-Messing theory. Besides the original papers, though, I don't know any good expository literature on this topic (crystalline representations, etc.). Can someone recommend someone who is outside this field some articles to learn about the main results?